# C++ library import with problem when adding the osg and the osgearth lib

Tags: c++, qt, osgi, qt-creator, osgearth

I try to add the osg and the osgearth lib to my Qt project.After qmake I try to build the whole project but something is wrong.Here are the errors and my .pro file
[image: errors]
[image: errors]
[image: .pro file]
[image: .pro file]

I have tried clear the whole project and qmake again,then rebuild the project,but it didn't work.
What I expect is that the osg lib imported successfully and the project has built correctly.

Comment: What is is that causes people to post text using image formats? Please post text as text.

Comment: I know nothing about this platform, but if I had to take a wild guess I would say that `OSG_PATH` should be `$$OSG_PATH`. Unless you really have installed everything in a directory called OSG_PATH, of course.

Comment: The dllimport part tells me that your code fails to link to an import library (.lib) for a dll.